# replace ternary nil check with ruby best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i find myself doing this quite a lot to protect against nil when the return of **some_method** returns nil.

```
a = a.some_method.present? ? a.some_method : []
```

is there a more ruby way to do it? I've tried using

```
a = []
a ||= a.some_method
```

but ofcourse that will just give me

```
a = []
```

thanks!

Comment: `a = a.some_method || []`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual pattern is:

```
result = method(args) || default_value
```

The `||` operator is short-circuiting. If the left-hand-side is true, it will not bother to evaluate the right hand side. In Ruby, `nil` is considered false. Hence if `nil` is returned (or `false`), the `||` evaluates the right-hand-side and returns that as the result.

Note the order of the left and right sides is important.

Answer (score 1):

You already got some good answers. Another approach — if this is a problem in your own code — would be to model your class after Ruby's standard library, e.g. `Hash#fetch`, so the user can just supply a block with an expression to be used as default value.

```
class Whatever
  def some_method
    result = nil # normally this would be computed
    return result unless result.nil?
    yield if block_given?
  end
end
```

The reason I explicitly check with `nil?` is for cases where `result` can be legitimately `false`. If you don't care about that or you know it won't happen feel free to change the condition (e.g. `unless result`).

Usage:

```
Whatever.new.some_method
#=> nil
Whatever.new.some_method { [] }
#=> []
Whatever.new.some_method { 1 + 1 }
#=> 2
```

Personally I think this is a nicer alternative to the explicit safe wrapper suggested elsewhere in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself needing a ternany or similar pattern more than once or twice for the same method, you may want to consider introducing a "safe" variant.

```
class A

  def some_method
    nil
  end

  def some_method_safe
    if value = self.some_method
      value
    else
      []
    end
  end

end

A.new.some_method_safe # => []
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your `some_method` is going to return an array or `nil`. If `some_method` is going to anything else that is not `present?` (`''`, `false`, `{}`, `[]`, `nil`) then you have a pretty strange interface on your hands. I think `!x.present?` casts a wider net than you need.

I'd guess that your logic is really more like:

```
x = a.some_method
x = [ ] if(x.nil?)
```

so all you really want to do is turn `nil` into an empty array and leave an array alone. [`Array#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_a) and [`NilClass#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_a) to exactly that so you can simply say:

```
x = a.some_method.to_a
```

The problem with `Array#to_a` is that it doesn't handle `Array` subclasses that well but that's a pretty rare problem.

In some contexts "not there" means `nil`, in others it means `0`, `''`, `[ ]`, ... so we have the convenient `to_X` and [`presence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) methods to conveniently hide the difference behind method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `a.some_method` returns either an array or `nil`, and if `nil` you want it to instead return an empty array. If that's correct, you could write:

```
a.some_method.to_a
```

If `a.some_method` returns an array `arr`, `arr.to_a #=> arr`. (See [Array#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-to_a).)

If `a.some_method` return `nil`, `nil.to_a #=> []`. (See [NilClass#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_a)).